# spss search for value in dataset

Tags: full-text-search, spss

I'd like to find any cases of a value (e.g., 0) in any cell in an SPSS database. What syntax would accomplish this?

(I came across a python script but don't have that option.)

Comment: Can you post at least the data structure ? Also, on stackoverflow it is a good idea to show that you are actually trying something, so post your attemps. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The attempts so far have been very labor-intensive: 
1. sort each column to see if any 0 values appear
2. use the explore function to check for 0 values for each variable
3. use find and replace for 0 values, but this returns any number with a 0 in it (and even trying to use the 'entire cell' option does not work for finding cells with just 0)

Comment: What is the data structure? What columns do you have ?

Comment: The data is set up as participant IDs in column 1, followed by scores on (many) tests in the remaining columns. For example, row 1 would have ID_001, row 2 would have a score like 15, row 3 would have another score like 3, etc. I want to find all the 0 values for cases where the data import should have been null but a 0 was added instead, which would impact any analyses. Because I have so many columns of test data, I hoped to find an efficient search function.

Comment: So all 0 ahould have been null ?

Comment: *sometimes
some may actually be true values, so I'd like to find the cases and evaluate each one

Answer (score 2):

It is still not very clear how you want to select those cases. But the below syntax will list in the output any cases which have ate least one "0" in any of the variables `var1`,`var2` or `var3`. I am assuming CaseID is the case identifier variable.

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF ANY(0,var1,var2,var3).
LIST CaseID var1 var2 var3.
```

You can use as many variables as you want in the `ANY` function, and also on the `LIST` command.

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax will create a list of appearances of **0** within your data - In a separate file:

First creating some fake data to demonstrate on.

```
data list list/ID (a6) test1 to test6 (6f2).
begin data
ID_001 2 3 2 3 0 3
ID_002 3 4 0 4 3 4
ID_003 0 4 2 4 2 4
ID_004 7 0 1 2 8 3
ID_005 5 5 5 0 5 5
ID_006 4 5 4 5 4 0
end data.
dataset name origData.
```

Now to create the list:

```
dataset copy ForList.
dataset activate ForList. /* the list will be created from a copy of the data.
varstocases /make vals from test1 to test6/index testNum(vals).
select if vals=0.
```

You can use the list in the new file, or put it in the output window:

```
list ID testNum.
```